# Can't use core/jquery

Tags: theming, 8

I created my libraries.yml as shown in [Drupal 8 CSS/JS](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets).

#### .libraries.yml

```
 general:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/materialize-custom.css: {}
      css/main.css: {}
  js:
    js/materialize.min.js: {}
    js/main.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

My problem is that my main.js need jQuery to work.

#### main.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Initialize collapse button
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
});
```

I get this error.

> [image]

I don't understand why I have this error. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drupal doesn't provide you with an alias for jQuery, because these days it'll inevitably interfere with another library sometime later.

If you want `$` as an alias, you'll need to create it yourself:

```
(function($) {
  // your code...
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: To build on this, if you also require Drupal and drupalSettings libraries, they are also passed in like jQuery.